# rpcalc.c:257: fatal error: error writing to /var/tmp//cc7arLuk.s: No space left on device compilation terminated

Tags: c

I am getting an error that says

```
 rpcalc.c:257: fatal error: error writing to /var/tmp//cc7arLuk.s: No space left on device
compilation terminated.
```

I have looked for a solution but I don't really understand how to clear memory so I can compile my program from what I have found. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What does this have to do with putty?

Comment: gcc -Wall -std=c89 rpcalc.c -o rpcalc Is what I use to compile, and  puTTy is the terminal emulator I am using I thought it might change the solution so I included it

Comment: How much space do you have per `df -hk /var/tmp`?

Comment: Well… the message clearly tells you the issue. Disk space is not enough.

Comment: 9.8G it is 100% full, and I know it is full I don't know how to fix it hence the question.

Comment: You need to remove files from your disk system.  Or get extra disk, but there's probably a lot of junk you can clean up before getting more space.  You might be able to compress some files, but you need some free space to get started.

Comment: How can we be expected to know what can be cleared/removed on _your_ disk, on _your_ system, on _your_ computer? The answer is we can't. You have to make room for the compilation, and that's something we can't help you with.

Comment: Your disk is full.  What more needs to be said?  Delete all your pron and copyrighted Hollywood/TV series downloads.

Comment: Also, 9.8G - most systems have more RAM than that.

Comment: Not what I asked, I want to know how to clear my disk not what to clear. As in how would I delete anything from my disk then I will decide what to get rid of.

Comment: The standard command to remove files is `rm`, run at the shell command line where you are running your compilation.

Comment: Umm... you don't know how to delete files?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler you are using writes temporary files to `/var/tmp`.  On your machine, there is not enough space left for the compiler to write the file it needs.  You can see this because `df` reports that the filesystem `/var/tmp` is a part of is at 100%.

In my experience, `/var/tmp` is not cleared on reboot.  So it can accumulate lots of unneeded files.  The solution is to look at the files in `/var/tmp` and remove those you don't need.  If that does not work, set the environment variable TMPDIR to point to a directory with space in it.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I originally tried but I could not find /var/tmp to clear it could you tell me the file path or where to look?

Comment: The space is on the machine you're using putty to connect to.  You need to login to the machine, find where you're using lots of disk space, and decide what you can delete to free up space.  Do you need the old version of ... your favourite software?  Do you need the installer image from 3 years ago still?

Answer (score 0):

user4872257. I do believe that you and I both go to the same university, mainly because we both had this problem yesterday and are both working on a program called rpcalc. The issue was with the IT department not emptying their tmp folder, I went down and spoke with them about it. The server should now be working fine, you might try once again compiling your code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

@user4872257 jump to ~ folder, type "cd /" and then type "ls", you will find "var" folder.